# Scheduling multiple cron jobs one after the other

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron

I am working on a Spring MVC based project, where I have a requirement to schedule multiple cron jobs which will execute one after the other. I am not getting any way to achieve this, any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want just small scheduling fictions check this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling otherwise if you want big job scheduling project check http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/